IoT Hub: Device Groups and Deployments Not Visible After Adding Tag Group
I'm working with Azure IoT Hub and have created a device group by adding tags to my devices. However, after adding the tag group, I can't see my groups or deployments in the Groups tab.
device tap
And here is a screenshot showing the empty Groups tab where I expected to see my device groups:
Group Empty
i need to view my deviece group
I've tried the following to resolve the issue:
Refreshed the IoT Hub dashboard.
Re-logged into my Azure account.
Checked permissions and roles for IoT Hub.


How are you adding tags to devices and creating the tag group? Please provide the details and share the document you followed. Additionally, please include the code and any errors in text format.

To see updates in a group and add tags to a group in IoT Hub, you need to add updates using Device Update for IoT Hub.
Refer to this document for details on how to view device groups. You can also consult this document for different methods to import updates.
Below are the steps from the documentation:

Ensure you have an IoT Hub configured with Device Update, and use an Ubuntu 18.04 device (either physical or virtual).

In Azure IoT, register the device and create a module identity.


az iot du update init v5 --update-provider Microsoft --update-name AptUpdate --update-version 1.0.0 --compat manufacturer=Contoso model=Vacuum --step handler=microsoft/script:1 properties="{\"installedCriteria\":\"1.0\"}" --file path="C:\\Users\\Tutorial_Simulator\\Tutorial_Simulator\\TutorialImportManifest_Sim.importmanifest.json"





Refer to the document to import an update and upload update files.


